# Artifacts when Fading problem with IE and Jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, artifact

Open this site in IE8 (not sure about 7)
http://www.koffeebreak.info/

See how the main div that fades in gets the black artifacts all over it?

I found this fix on another StackOverflow question: 
[Fading issues in Internet Explorer 7 when using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652286/fading-issues-in-internet-explorer-7-when-using-jquery)

But when I applied it:

```
jQuery("#homepagewelcome").children().fadeTo('fast', 1, function(){
            document.getElementById("#homepagewelcomeContent").style.removeAttribute("filter"); 

            });
```

Nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#homepagewelcomeContent")[0].style.removeAttribute("filter");
```

Comment: I guess that is as close as it's going to get for me... it works, but it flickers horribly. I'll just do a appear effect for IE. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah no problem... I really hate the issue, I stopped using fading images due to it on a current project.