# jQuery FadeIn, FadeOut Div - IE7 bug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a `div` that will fade in and out on hover in FF, but in IE7 it just hides and shows with no animation. Here is my code:

```
#nav-buttons {
    display:none;
    width:894px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
}
#left-button, #right-button {
position:absolute;
width:46px;
height:76px;        
}
#left-button {
background:url("images/arrows.png") no-repeat scroll -88px -60px transparent;
left:-46px;
}
#left-button:hover {
background-position:-88px -260px;
}
#right-button {
background:url("images/arrows.png") no-repeat scroll 3px -60px transparent;
right:-43px;
}
#right-button:hover {
background-position:4px -260px;
}


----------
<div id="contents">
<div id="nav-buttons">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="left-button"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="right-button"></a>
</div>
 other html....
</div>

----------

$(document).ready(function() {                  
    $("#contents").hover(function() {
        $("#nav-buttons").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: If someone have ie7 here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KMmSB/5/

Comment: Edited post. Try removing filter.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but since "content" seemed to work and the buttons didn't, try removing the dash "-" to see if that's the issue. Probably not, but I'm having flashbacks to old Netscape underscore issues.

Comment: Oh, I just read. You didn't say anything about PNG in the original post. I added a delay to the last code, but there is an issue online about it, and there is a suggestion to put the image in a container and fade the container. The delay is for the alpha channel, because apparently when it works it looks horrible. You might have to play around with it. .. I think the filter line might have to change as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by fadeToggle() each button directly instead of the `<div id=nav-buttons>` here is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                  
   $("#contents").hover(function() {
      $("#left-button").fadeToggle("slow");
      $("#right-button").fadeToggle("slow");
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have IE7, but maybe try this for now. Doesn't fix, but shows content when it needs to be shown... Well, unsure on IE7, but had kind of a similar prob with IE9.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                  
    $("#contents").hover( function() {
        $("#nav-buttons").fadeToggle("slow").queue(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            $(this).dequeue();
          });
    });
});
```

Also, maybe get rid of "display:none;", because it's acting odd... or did you want that?

edit: I found that it may work just to re-add fadeToggle in the queue function. Ah, you want something to show when you hover over something else. I get it now. Maybe just add another fadeToggle in the queue, or fade out when the mouse is no longer over the div.

edit2: seeing as you want to appear and disappear, maybe this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                  
    $("#contents").mouseenter( function() {
        $("#nav-buttons").fadeIn("slow");
    }).mouseleave( function() {
        $("#nav-buttons").fadeOut("slow");
    });       
});
```

If you want to change to fadeToggle, I'd suggest removing display:none when you call it or it will keep going off screen. Then you can put it back when you are leaving.

Edit3: according to link try:

[Fading issues in Internet Explorer 7 when using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652286/fading-issues-in-internet-explorer-7-when-using-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){                  
    $("#contents")
        .mouseenter( function() {
            $("#nav-buttons").delay(200).fadeIn(function(){
              $(this).css("filter",'');
            });
        })
        .mouseleave( function() {
            $("#nav-buttons").delay(200).fadeOut(function(){
              $(this).css("filter",'');
            });
        });
});
```

If that doesn't work, you're probably going to have to use straight css.

Comment: Very weird. I removed display:none and switched my jquery to yours...same issue. It hides and shows perfectly as my code did, but still no animation(opacity). I tried both your code and mine in FF and it fades in and out nicely. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just tried and works in IE9 without filter, but breaks FF for me. You might have to do a browser check if it does work.

Comment: No dice :( It just hides and shows like .show() or .hide() would. I guess my users won't be getting any fancy animation. Strange thing is Im able to fadeIn and fadeOut the #contents div. I wonder if it has anything to do with the png image background on the left-button and right-button. I know IE had some issues with PNG images in the past

Answer (score 0):

fadeToggle is Buggy in IE7 ! If you get it working somehow you will also see if you fading font that IE7 will make some strange antialiasing to this font while fiding in or out... very ugly.

Use color animation (if possible becouse of background) or try .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() instead